# phpQuery перебор массива с ссылками на товар

Tags: php, phpquery

Как правильно сделать что-бы был перебор массива file 
с библиотекой phpQuery

```
 $file = [
      "https://digbox.ru/dji_kvadrokopter_dji_spark_alpin_white.html",
      "https://digbox.ru/kvadrokopter_dji_mavic_pro__pult_du_.html",
      "https://digbox.ru/kvadrokopter_dji_phantom_4_pro.html",
    ];

    $product_link = file_get_contents($file);

    phpQuery::newDocument($product_link);

    $product = array();

    $product['_NAME_'] = trim(pq("h1")->text());
    $product['_META_TITLE_'] = trim(pq("h1")->text());
    $product['_QUANTITY_'] = "15";

    $price = pq(".aside-top .price ins")->text();
    $product['_PRICE_'] = preg_replace('~[^0-9]+~','',$price); ;

    $product['_IMAGE_'] = "https://digbox.ru".pq(".product-slider .slider-init li a")->attr('href');


    $product['_IMAGES_'] = '';
    $images = pq(".product-slider .slider-init li a");
    $dublicat_img = $product['_IMAGE_'].",";
    foreach ( $images as $p ) {
        $product['_IMAGES_'].= str_replace("https://digbox.ru,",'',str_replace($dublicat_img,"","https://digbox.ru".$p->getAttribute('href').","));
    }

    $product['_MANUFACTURER_'] = 'DJI';
    $product['_MODEL_'] = str_replace("Арт: ","",pq(".item-info .item-id")->text());
    $atr = pq(".char-list");
    foreach ( $atr as $p ) {
        $p = pq($p);
        $h2 = $p->find('div')->htmlOuter();
        $delimiters = Array('<div class="char-item">',"<span>-</span>");
        $attributes = multiexplode($delimiters,$h2);
        foreach ($attributes as $attribute) {
            list($attributeName,$attributeVal) = $attribute;
            $attributeName= preg_replace("/\s{2,}/"," ",trim($attributeName));
            $attributeVal = str_replace(";",'',trim($attributeVal));
            if(!empty($attributeName)){
                $product['_ATTRIBUTES_'] .= "Характеристика|{$attributeName}|{$attributeVal}" . PHP_EOL;
            }
        }
    }

    phpQuery::unloadDocuments();
```

Comment: `file_get_contents` принимает один путь, а не массив. Воспользуйтесь `foreach`.

Comment: @ЕгорБанин То есть убрать эту функцию и напрямую перебирать массив ?

Comment: попробуйте сделать `$file` строкой, например: `$file = "https://digbox.ru/dji_kvadrokopter_dji_spark_alpin_white.html";`. Тогда `file_get_contents` должен отработать нормально. Теперь, если вы хотите распарсить несколько ссылок, то повторите это для других адресов. Повторять удобно не копируя и вставляя код, а воспользовавшись циклом [foreach](http://php.net/manual/ru/control-structures.foreach.php).